# How to infer the return type of a conditional return type TS function

Tags: typescript

I have a type of a conditional return function

```
type X = <A extends boolean>(x: A) => A extends true ? string : boolean
```

I want to get the return type of a specific case,
something like

```
type Z = X<true> //string
```

How do I do that?

Comment: did you try using `ReturnType<T>`?

Comment: Yep, I get `string | boolean`

Comment: You can't do this in TS. If you have a function `x` of type `X`, you can write `ReturnType<typeof x<true>>` , but with just a type named `X` it's not possible.  TS doesn't have "instantiation types" and for now there are only open feature requests like https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50481.  See other q/a for the current situation